# How to select several rows in a dataframe based on index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame object whose label index is not a position integer but a name, how can I extract several rows:

e.g. select the 3rd, 4th row

```
df.iloc[[2],[3]]
```

This gives me an error, telling me I could only extract one row at a time.

Comment: Try `df.iloc[[2,3],:]` or `df.ix[[2,3],:]`. If neither works then you will need to show the data you got.

Comment: But the problem is, my rows are not consecutive. I need to pick many rows in a dataframe with 240 rows and 4 columns:     df.iloc[[0],[3],[4],[5],[9],[11],[14],[26],[28],[30],[39],[45],[46],[48],[52],[56],[66],[67],[72],[75]] does not work.

Comment: Got it! Simply write it as df.iloc[[0,3,4,5,9...]]

Answer (score 0):

[loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is a standard way to extract data via the labels of an index.

[iloc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is a standard way to extract data via the positions of an index.

Consider the following dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 4), list('abcd'), list('ABCD'))

df
```

[image]

What you said you did seems to work just fine:

```
df.iloc[[2], [3]]
```

[image]